# mySQL sort field by two criteria

Tags: php, mysql

Due to very strange conventions by the hosting party I have API pull data that is ordered like this:

```
[car0]
[car0]
[car1]
[car2]
[car]
```

if i do a sql retrieve on my database and `order by name asc`

I get

```
[car]
[car0]
[car0]
[car1]
[car2]
```

I need the columns to be in the exact same order.

Is there some way for me to sort by perhaps string length first then sort by name asc, so the data retrieved from mysql can look like the data from the URL:

Comment: `order by insert_date_time ASC`

Comment: @user2684452 if you mean order by timestamp the date is the exact same down to the second, I'm not sure if adding miliseconds will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
order by CASE SUBSTRING(name, 4)
  WHEN '' THEN -1
  else SUBSTRING(name, 4) end asc
```